# Value of $a$ so that function is increasing

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

Find the maximum value of $a$ so that function $f(x)=x^2-8ax+2013$ is an increasing function in $(2012,2014)$.

Here $f'(x)=2x-8a$

For increasing function:

$f'(x) \geq 0$ which gives

$a\leq x/4$

Maximum value of x is approaching $2014$, we get $a_{max}=2014/4$

Is my approach correct or am I missing something?

Comment: Looks OK to me.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f(x)$ has to be increasing on all of $(2012,2014)$, you need to set $a_{max} = \frac{2012}{4} = 503$, so that it increases near $x=2012$ as well.